# Why is the matplotlib plot produced by executing `org-babel-execute-src-block` contain errors?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python

## The context

Consider the following Emacs configuration

```
$ cat ~/.emacs.d/init.el
(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages
                             '((python . t)))
$
```

and the following Org mode file

```
$ cat ~/Experiments/main.org
#+begin_src python :tangle main.py :results file :file 1.png
from matplotlib import pyplot
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 4, 9]

pyplot.plot(x, y)
pyplot.savefig('1.png')
#+end_src
$
```

If I tangle the Python code block (i.e. execute `org-babel-tangle`), execute the Python script (i.e. execute `python main.py` in a shell) and obtain the hash of the resulting image I get

```
$ pwd
/home/myusername/Experiments
$ python main.py
$ sha512sum 1.png && du -h 1.png
084ffd63ec53665c21fc3eaba5f5ec3622d4d27a97f89cb67e3b436ca8093467272bbc239fd0e60dde27f5207ee33392f5b83b9eca1427efe7523450d92a6a8c  1.png
20K    1.png
```

I can open `1.png` with `firefox` and `mpv` without any problems.

If I execute the code block in Emacs by pressing `C-c C-c` (i.e. execute `org-babel-execute-src-block`) while the cursor is in the `#+BEGIN_SRC` block, I get the following

```
$ sha512sum 1.png && du -h 1.png
e39d05b72f25767869d44391919434896bb055772d7969f74472032b03bc18418911f3b0e6dd47ff8f3b2323728225286c3cb36914d28dc7db40bdd786159c0a  1.png
4.0K    1.png
```

Note that the size of `1.png` is significantly lower than the size shown above.

## Additional context

In addition to that, if I try to open the image with `mpv`, I get the following error

```
$ mpv 1.png
 (+) Video --vid=1 (png 1.000fps)
[ffmpeg/video] png: Invalid PNG signature 0x00000000.
Error while decoding frame!
(Paused) V: 00:00:01 / 00:00:01 (100%)
[ffmpeg/video] png: Invalid PNG signature 0x00000000.
Error while decoding frame!
(Paused) V: 00:00:01 / 00:00:01 (100%)
```

An error is also shown when I try to open the image in `firefox` (see image below)

[image]

The error is not present in both `firefox` and `mpv` when producing the image `1.png` by executing the script in a shell.

## The question

- Why is the file `1.png` obtained after executing `org-babel-execute-src-block` different than the one produced by tangling the `#+BEGIN_SRC` block and executing `python main.py` in a shell?
- Why does the resulting file `1.png` contain errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `:results file` to `:results file graphics`.

Comment: Thanks. It solved the issue! I will have to read on the `graphics` header argument I think.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an explanation to go with @darcamo's answer:

When you say `:results file :file 1.png`, babel creates a file `1.png` containing the result of running the block (in the default case of `:results value`) or the standard output (in the `:results output` case) and puts a link to that file as the result of the evaluation of the block.

In your case, the source block returns the value that `pyplot.savefig(...)` returns, which happens to be `None`. The block also writes the image into `1.png` (that's what `savefig()` does after all), but then babel saves the result and overwrites the image with the word `None`. So you end up with a "corrupt" PNG file: check it with `ls -l` and `cat`: it's 4 bytes long containing the characters `None`.

---

OTOH, when you say `:results file link :file 1.png` (or `:results file graphics :file 1.png` - they do the same thing), babel just puts a link to a (non-existent) file called `1.png` as the result of the evaluation but *does not create the file*. It just runs the block which, as a side effect, produces the file `1.png` - a real PNG file in this case, since babel does not overwrite it. Note that there is a conspiracy involved: babel creates a link to `1.png` but has no idea what file (if any) the block is going to produce: *you* have to make sure that the file produced by the block has the same name - if the names are different, then the link is not going to work.