# orgmode - do not export example block

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I try to use a example block as input to babel block, I want to export babel results only, in below example, I try to add exports none to example block but it doesn't work, the example content exported to html page as well.

How can I disable example block export?

```
* example
#+name: input
#+begin_example :exports none
5 1 3 2 0
#+end_example

#+begin_src python :results output :eval yes :var x=input :exports results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array(x.split())
x = x.astype(int)
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x)
plt.savefig("test.png")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:

[[./test.png]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the example in a separate section and tag it `noexport`:

```org
* example input                                                        :noexport:
#+name: input
#+begin_example
5 1 3 2 0
#+end_example

* example code 
#+begin_src python :results output :eval yes :var x=input :exports results
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np

  x = np.array(x.split())
  x = x.astype(int)
  fig,ax = plt.subplots()
  ax.plot(x)
  plt.savefig("./test.png")
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
[[file:./test.png]]
```

BTW, the way that you have your headers does not really work to produce a result: the code block produces no output on its stdout so `:results output` makes it produce an empty result. The output file is a *side effect* of the code block execution, so Org mode (and babel) don't know anything about it. Did you add the result by hand?

A better way to do that is to use the following header line instead:

```org
#+begin_src python :results file link :file test.png :eval yes :var x=input :exports results
...
```

That tells babel to produce a link to a file named `test.png`, but babel does not create the file: it expects the code block to produce it.

See e.g.
[this Emacs SE question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61534/why-is-the-matplotlib-plot-produced-by-executing-org-babel-execute-src-block-c/61545#61545) for more details.

Comment: Great, is it possible for python to use the name file :file parameter to save the figure? now it's hardcode as plt.savefig("./test.png").

Comment: It should be possible, right? Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it.  I hate repeating myself.

Answer (score 3):

What I do for cases like this, where I do not want the input to some src block exported, is put the input (the example block in your case) in a drawer and set the option d:nil so as to not export drawers.

```
* example
:input:
#+name: input
#+begin_example
5 1 3 2 0
#+end_example
:end:
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think org offers any way to exclude example blocks from exporting. A possible work-around: if you don't want the example to show up in your export, does it need to be an example? You could make it a bash code block instead:

```
* example

#+name: input
#+begin_src bash :exports none
echo 5 1 3 2 0
#+end_src

#+begin_src python :results output :eval yes :var x=input :exports results
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array(x.split())
x = x.astype(int)
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x)
plt.savefig("test.png")
#+end_src
```

Comment: Good idea, I use example block since I wish do not change original text block then do processing in python code.